# Is there a more efficient way to find the average of a large number of matrices?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

so I have around 300 matrices right now which isn't too bad, but I want to make my code reusable in the future and so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to find the average. The matrices I have are 88x88, and the way I want to average it is to get just one matrix at the end, where each [i][j] value is the average of all the [i][j] values in the other 300 matrices.

```
mean = []
smaller = []


for j in range(88):
        for i in range(88):
            for k in range(len(listof_matrices)):
                smaller.append(listof_matrices[k][i][j])
                mean.append(str(float(sum(smaller))/float(len(smaller))))
```

Basically the way the code works is 3 nested loops (I know...) which goes first appends the values of a single [i][j] position in all k matrices, finds the mean, adds that to a mean list which stores it, and does that again for all i and all j. Surely there must be a faster way. Cheers

Comment: numpy is your friend. `np.mean(listof_matrices, axis=0)`

Comment: @Julien does this work even if my matrices are not numpy arrays, and just normal lists? Or should I convert them all to numpy arrays?

Comment: In most cases numpy automatically converts for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely use `numpy`. I'll explain to you with a reproducible example

#### `Setup`

```
m1 = np.array([[3, 6, 2], [5, 6, 3], [2, 7, 2]])
m2 = np.array([[1, 5, 7], [9, 9, 8], [1, 6, 6]])
m3 = np.array([[9, 8, 3], [3, 5, 4], [7, 3, 3]])
list_of_matrices = [m1, m2, m3]
```

#### `Solution`

Then just use `np.mean`

```
np.mean(list_of_matrices, axis=0)
```

Outputs

```
array([[4.33333333, 6.33333333, 4.        ],
       [5.66666667, 6.66666667, 5.        ],
       [3.33333333, 5.33333333, 3.66666667]])
```

So for your example, the only `loop` you might need to do is to create the `list_of_matrices`, which you already have to do anyway. Then, you just call `np.mean`, which will generate your matrix of means with a vectorized solution. Timing will be *extremely* faster than your three-nested-for-loops approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `numpy` for these purposes.

Let's say you have the matrices in a single `numpy` array. Example:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
    [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
    ],
    [
        [5, 6],
        [7, 8]
    ],
    [
        [9, 10],
        [11, 12]
    ],
])
```

you could get the averages with just

```
np.sum(matrix, axis=0)/float(matrix.shape[0])
```

as `np.sum(matrix, axis=0)` sums all the array by it's outermost axis and `matrix.shape[0]` gives you the amount of matrices contained in it.

Also `numpy`'s performance is much **much** greater than raw python's

Comment: why not just np.mean